# Apache Kafka - Doesn't seem to load balance in Kafka Cluster

Tags: java, runtime-error, apache-kafka, broker

I am using Kafka `2.9.2-0.8.1` version..

From the documentation, it seems that `load balancing` is done automatically for the configured cluster.

Here is my Java producer configuration:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("batch.size", "200");
props.put("producer.type", "async");
props.put("connect.timeout.ms", "5000");
props.put("request.required.acks", "0");
props.put("metadata.broker.list", "10.10.73.52:9092,10.10.70.15:9092");
props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.DefaultEncoder");
props.put("partitioner.class", "kafka.producer.DefaultPartitioner");
```

Note: I have kept all the default configurations, which were provided by the Kafka distribution..

Zookeeper seems to have discovered my other broker : 10.10.70.15.. when I checked the logs..

I have created a `test-topic` on one of the brokers.. using the `console-producer.sh`.. which then created appropriate `directory` in `/tmp/kafka-logs` folder in all the other registered `brokers` in `zookeeper`.

--> `./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper 10.10.73.52:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partitions 2 --topic test-topic`

I have used the following provided line to subscribe to the topic on both broker machines..

--> `./kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper 10.10.73.52:2181 --topic test-topic`

Producer code:

```
KeyedMessage<String, byte[]> publishData = new KeyedMessage<String, byte[]>("test-topic", data);
producer.send(publishData);
```

I see that `both the brokers` receive the same data.. and load is not balanced.

Do I need to implement any other load-balance/partition logic?

Any ideas what am I missing here?

Comment: It looks like you're using replication factor 2. So all values are replicated to 2 machine. To see load balancing in action either set replication factor to 1 or add third broker.

Comment: I see..Thanks for the reply.. So the replication factor should not be equal to the number of brokers? So, adding 3 brokers, with a replication factor 1, should load-balance? Also, I believe I was checking for load-balancing thingy incorrectly.. I started the console-consumer on both my brokers, listening for same topic.. probably that's why I was seeing the same data? How does that work?